# How to access the String object inserted as fact in drools

Tags: drools

I am inserting String as a fact in the drool's rule engine.
How can I use it in the rules.

```
String fact = "collegeName";
ksession.insert(fact);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
rule "TEST"
when
    $s: String (this == "collegeName")
then
    //Do something
end
```

The interesting thing is why are you inserting things that you don't know how to handle :P

Hope it helps,